# after i have edited my php code it doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
    $queries = array(
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/home?limit=50'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
        array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/photos?limit=6'),
        );

    // POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
    try{
        $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
    }catch(Exception $o){
        error_log($o);
    }

    //Return values are indexed in order of the original array, content is in ['body'] as a JSON
    //string. Decode for use as a PHP array.
    $user_info      = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], TRUE);
    $feed           = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], TRUE);
    $friends_list   = json_decode($batchResponse[2]['body'], TRUE);
```

I have edited the code to be

```
$queries = array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user);

try{
    $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
}catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}

$user_info      = json_decode($batchResponse['body'], TRUE);
```

But it doesn't work correctly anymore and no value when i echo $user_info

What is the wrong which i did ?

Comment: "Doesn't work correctly anymore" - not helpful at all

Comment: What is the error returned by the FB API call?

Comment: If it did work and doesn't now, undo your changes.

Comment: @KevinDTimm & jamis0n : no value when i echo $user_info

Comment: Select an answer if one of them solved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

you altered the nested array structure. I think you need:

```
$queries = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user)
    );
```

instead of

```
$queries = array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user);
```

Answer (score 0):

last line:

```
     array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/photos?limit=6'),
```

shouldnt have the coma at the end

```
     array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/photos?limit=6')
```

Comment: 1) You're looking at the unmodified code, and 2) that trailing comma on the last element of an array doesn't cause an error.

Comment: it used you. im old school

Comment: PHP dev for 10 years here - keep up with your craft.  ;)

Comment: well, i haven't been coding for maybe 7-8 years, but still in php-dev myself ;)